# Rails failure to load shoulda-matchers 3.1.1 gem, undefined method `allow_value' for #<RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, testing, rspec, rspec-rails, shoulda

'shoulda-matchers' gem is not loading when running rspec tests.

Error:
`NoMethodError: undefined method 'allow_value' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::Contact::ActiveModelValidationss:0x007fef1021b310>`

versions being used:
`Ruby 2.2.2`
`Rails 4.2.1`
`shoulda-matchers 3.1.1`

Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '4.2.1'
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.0'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
  gem 'shoulda-matchers', '~> 3.1'
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'rubocop', require: false
end
```

rails_helper.rb:

```
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
abort("The Rails environment is running in production mode!") if Rails.env.production?
require 'spec_helper'
require 'rspec/rails'

ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true
  config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!
  config.filter_rails_from_backtrace!

  Shoulda::Matchers.configure do |config|
    config.integrate do |with|
      with.test_framework :rspec
      with.library :active_record
      with.library :rails
    end
  end
end
```

spec_helper.rb:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  require 'factory_girl_rails'
  require 'shoulda/matchers'
  config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods
  config.expect_with :rspec do |expectations|
    expectations.include_chain_clauses_in_custom_matcher_descriptions = true
  end
  config.mock_with :rspec do |mocks|
    mocks.verify_partial_doubles = true
  end
end
```

contact_spec.rb:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Contact do

  FactoryGirl.define do
    factory :contact do
      first_name "Alice"
      last_name  "Bob"
      email_address "alicebob@example.com"
      phone_number "555-555-5555"
      company_name "ExampleCompany"
    end
  end

  it "has a valid factory" do
    expect(build(:contact)).to be_valid
  end

  describe "ActiveModel validations" do
    it { expect(:contact).to allow_value("alice_bob@example.com").for(:email_address) }
  end
end
```

Sorry for all the code. Please note I am using shoulda-matchers version 3.1.1 and adding 'require: false` to the gemfile is no longer needed as noted here https://robots.thoughtbot.com/shoulda-matchers-3-0

I have also tried adding shoulda-matchers to its own test environment in the Gemfile as below but found no change

```
group :test do
  gem 'shoulda-matchers', '~> 3.1'
end
```

I've looked online and have found similar problems with solutions that don't work in my case. Any help or advice would be great!

Comment: did you manage to solve your issue?

Answer (score 2):

In my case, the problem was that the tested class was not an `ActiveRecord` item, so `shoulda` did not load methods such as `allow_value` by default.

Solution was to add `type: :model` in the `_spec.rb` file:

```
RSpec.describe MyTestedClass, type: :model do
  ...
end
```

Comment: This was the case for my custom validator spec, had nothing to do with loading like many other sources suggest.

Answer (score 0):

The fix that should get you green again is to change:

`it { expect(:contact).to allow_value("alice_bob@example.com").for(:email_address) }`

to

`it { expect(build(:contact)).to allow_value("alice_bob@example.com").for(:email_address) }`

in the same way as your first test, as your second test is expecting the symbol `:contact` to `allow_value`, rather than the object created in your factory.

Further, I'd recommend moving your factory definition into its own file under `spec/factories/contact.rb` rather than inline in your spec, and memoise the contact object in a `let` method, so you'd have a spec that looks like:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Contact do
  let(:contact) { build(:contact) }

  it "has a valid factory" do
    expect(contact).to be_valid
  end

  describe "ActiveModel validations" do
    it { expect(contact).to allow_value("alice_bob@example.com").for(:email_address) }
  end
end
```